# first time flyer and want to take thin metal sign

Tags: airports

I have a metal sign that I would like to take with me on my flight to CO. Is this object allowed either in my carry-on or checked luggage. I'm a first time flyer.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific of what your 'thin metal sign' is. If it's a dog mark like piece of jewellery it's unlikely to be a problem, but if it's a blade, it might be an issue.

Comment: also size and dimensions, and weight of said sigh? what type of metal?

Answer (score 3):

Is it allowed, yes.  Can you take it in your carry-on luggage, depends on size and edges (are they sharp).  Can you put it in your checked luggage, yes.  Will the bag get opened and inspected by TSA, likely.